# Get upper and lower value surrounding a number

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given a number, I would like to get the immediately lower and upper values from a table like this:

```
4.420
4.570
5.120
5.620
6.120
6.370
7.120
7.370
7.870
8.120
8.370
```

For example, if I use 6.20 as parameter, the query should return 6.12 and 6.37.

I'm doing this because I want to calculate if a financial option is At the money.

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3.

Comment: We can assume the column is defined `NOT NULL` and indexed? Or even the PK (indexed automatically)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with all_numbers as (
   select nr, 
          lag(nr,1,nr) over (order by nr) as prev_value,
          lead(nr,1,nr) over (order by nr) as next_value
   from numbers           
)
select *
from all_numbers
where 6.20 between prev_value and next_value;
```

For completeness I was playing around with another solution:

```
select *
from numbers
where nr >= (select max(nr) from numbers where nr < 6.20)
  and nr <= (select min(nr) from numbers where nr > 6.20);
```

And to my surprise this was actually faster than the version with the window functions with an index on the `nr` column: 0.2 seconds vs. 2.7 seconds on a table with 2.8 million rows.

Here are the execution plans:

- version with window function: http://explain.depesz.com/s/Bse3
- version with sub-select: http://explain.depesz.com/s/L8V

Another possible solution is to install the btree_gist extension and then use the "distance" operator that comes with it: `<->`

As the result of the `<->` is a value (the distance between the two arguments) you would need to define a threshold that is low enough:

```
select nr
from numbers
where nr <-> 6.20 < 0.05;
```

or use an `order by nr <-> 6.20 limit 1`.

This took about 1 second on my test table

This version took about 1 second on my test table.

Comment: The first query is a performance hog and should not be used. GiST indexes (or the distance operator `<->`) are not very good tools for the task.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: I was surprised by that myself. I assumed that a single run over the table would be faster than three scans. But apparently I was wrong. The `<->` actually isn't that bad, it was more out of curiosity that I tried it.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from
(
   SELECT col, lag(col) OVER (ORDER BY col) before_value, lead(col) OVER (ORDER BY col) after_value
      FROM foo order by col  
) A
   WHERE 6.20 between before_value and after_value limit 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

With an index on `nr`, this is going to be **fastest**:

```
(SELECT nr FROM tbl WHERE nr < 6.20 ORDER BY nr DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT nr FROM tbl WHERE nr > 6.20 ORDER BY nr LIMIT 1);
```

Parentheses needed.

Two tuples fetched from the index with the cheapest possible plan.

Shorter, slightly slower:

```
SELECT max(nr) AS nr FROM t WHERE nr < 6.20
UNION ALL
SELECT min(nr) AS nr FROM t WHERE nr > 6.20;
```

Note that GIN or GiST indexes are *not* going to help. A default B-tree index is as fast  as it gets (and that is *very* fast).

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e0013/2)** comparing all queries posted so far.

#### Benchmark

Execution times on sqlfiddle.com are *unreliable*. Test in your own db to get reliable numbers. It's simple. I got these numbers from `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, best of 5 from a temp table with 100k rows (like in the fiddle) on 10 year old hardware:

```
a_horse 1  -- 766 ms (!!)
Houari     -- 0.463 ms
a_horse 2  -- 0.165 ms
erwin 2    -- 0.130 ms
erwin 1    -- 0.108 ms
```

Comment: Hmm, the time difference between my solution and houari doesn't make sense to me. His statement is identical to my first one - is this the effect of the `limit` clause? (Which doesn't return both values that leonardorame wants)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: You are using a CTE, which is an *optimization barrier* (and generally more expensive). `LIMIT` may have an effect, too, but I don't think that's to blame. My money is on the CTE.

Comment: Seems to be the `limit`. With limit: http://explain.depesz.com/s/Bh7q  without limit: http://explain.depesz.com/s/xKT3 and my cte version: http://explain.depesz.com/s/C8y6 (your testdata)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Well, it's both. Thinking about it, it makes sense. With `LIMIT 1` the planner knows that only a single row is retrieved and can optimize the plan.